# how can i solve this pyinstaller issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

iam a new python coder so iam still learning . i coded a simple gui python calculator and I am trying to transform my python file of code to .exe file using pyinstaller from how I saw online .i had no problems with installing pyinstaller but when I write the following ( pyinstaller --onefile -w simplecalculator.py) at cmd i get this:

```
C:\Users\sony vaio 2012>pyinstaller --onefile -w simplecalculator.py
120 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.1
120 INFO: Python: 3.9.0
120 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
128 INFO: wrote C:\Users\sony vaio 2012\simplecalculator.spec
128 INFO: UPX is not available.
script 'C:\Users\sony vaio 2012\simplecalculator.py' not found
```

I don't know what does that mean and also I am very sure there is no problems with the file name. I changed it multiple times but idk why it is saying not found
thanks...

Comment: Is the file in the same directory you're running pyinstaller from?

Comment: thank you very much after running some search I tried to use windows powershell in the same directory using shift + right click and it worked but I still wanna know how can I use cmd instead and get same result

Comment: I don't know. There's nothing wrong with what you posted and it's not reprodicble. I can only imagine you're not running pyinstaller in the same directory the file is in.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try use py2exe, just need to create a setup.py file with few especifications.

Comment: it turns out it is only for python 2.7

Comment: that's not true, I use it in 3.6. here is the link of the official page https://pypi.org/project/py2exe/ Python versions included in the official development cycle are supported (from 3.6 to 3.9 included)

Comment: oh sorry my bad i didn't search well as i mentioned iam a beginner.. thank you